# PhantomJS render fails for a big page

Tags: rendering, phantomjs

When I take a screenshot of a webpage with PhantomJS 1.9.8, I have a test case where the output is always a zero size file. I tried several debugging options with page.onError, I see some errors related with Facebook plugins and scripts, but nothing very helpful...

So when PhantomJS fails on rendering a page, is there a way to know what's going on above the status of the `render()` function?

URL: http://www.santenatureinnovation.com/verrues-un-nombre-incroyable-de-solutions/

Comment: I haven't encountered this problem before, but this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27158395

Comment: I just tried this solution, it didn't work. Rendered file is zero size. Maybe you could test by yourself, the URL is [this one](http://www.santenatureinnovation.com/verrues-un-nombre-incroyable-de-solutions/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is so big that it uses between 600 and 700 **MB** of RAM to render the image. The dimensions of the resulting image are 960 x 141524 (sic!). Make sure you have enough RAM and wait a little. It takes several seconds for the image to be rendered. The good thing is that JavaScript is single threaded and you don't have to add anything to wait for the rendering to finish, everything else freezes.

I tried it successfully with PhantomJS 1.9.7 and 1.9.8 (on windows) *without* special care to viewportSize or user agent string.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I wouldn't have thought of that. Indeed I don't have enough RAM on my computer to render such a huge page. Is it possible to handle this specific case in PhantomJS?

Comment: Certainly ... don't render such a big image. Since the comment thread is so long you may remove a big portion of it through `page.evaluate` and some DOM functions, render the page and repeat for so that a different portion of the comments are shown.